# To remove a letter between two particular words in a string

Tags: python-3.x

Edit : Sorry for no attempt

For example if I am given a string `a = 'tixeyetigefveftihe'`.So how can I remove the letters which occurs between the words 'ti' and 'e'.So my desired string would be 'tieyetiefveftie'

What I tried:

```
a = 'tixeyetigefveftihe'
x = a.split('ti')
if '' in x:
    x.remove('')
c = 0
for i in x:
    if i[1] == 'e':
        c = c + 1
print(c)
```

It seems to give the correct answer but I guess there must be shorter way to do this

Comment: hint: a for loop with two boolean state variables should be enough for a simple (but perfectly correct) implementation...

Answer (score 1):

Using regex or regular expressions for this task would be useful. You can learn and test your regex [here](https://regex101.com/).

Specifically, this is how you could do it using regex in Python.

```
import re
inputString = "tixeyetigefveftihe"
result = re.sub("(ti).*?(e)", "\g<1>\g<2>", inputString)
# result is "tieyetiefveftie"
```

What this regex does is that it creates two groups (of the initial characters and the later characters) and then matches all characters in between as well. This is replaced by the two groups themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across regex (regular expressions) as they will do exactly what you need. The are not the easiest thing to learn to use but very powerful.

This https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm looks like one good place where you could read up on it. Wikipedia also has a page on regex which lists lots of the available expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Split the function at ti, remove the non required characters and combine them agian using `.join()` function

```
a = 'tixeyetigefveftihe'
x = a.split('ti')
l = [i[1:] for i in x]
s = 'ti'.join(l)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is prettier then this answer. I just put this answer if you dont want to use regex or .join (Again regex solution is much better that this. This answer has hard codding. this code does not use any python libs)

```
a = 'tixeyetigefveftihe'
for ind in range(2, len(a)-2):
    if a[ind-1] == 'i' and a[ind-2] == 't':
        if  a[ind+1] == 'e':
            a= a[:ind] + a[ind+1:]
print (a)
```